# Why does “lineage” retain the "e" when the suffix "-age" is added?

Tags: suffixes, word-formation, exceptions

"Lineage" (/ˈlɪn·i·ɪdʒ/) is equivalent to "line" + "-age". Other such nouns lose the "e" when this suffix is added:

| Stem | + Suffix | = Noun |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anecdote | + Age | = Anecdotage |
| Cleave | + Age | = Cleavage |
| Dose | + Age | = Dosage |
| Store | + Age | = Storage |
| Use | + Age | = Usage |

Why does "lineage" stray from this trend and retain the "e" after we add "-age"?

Comment: It's arguably not "silent". I think it's usually pronounced (from IPA)  /ˈlɪn.i.ɪdʒ/  or  /ˈli-nē-ij/ for MW. However, MW does say there is an alternative pronunciation   /ˈli-nij /. That means the pronunciation you are used to hearing is probably from a specific geography.

Comment: The Online Etymological Dictionary posits an influence from 'lineal'; this reference should be included.

Comment: @Cascabel: This question is about spelling, not pronunciation.

Comment: Any question about "silent letters" refers to spelling. Letters are all silent; they are visual symbols and make no noise. It's their interpretation that causes the "silent letter" questions. "How are /layn/ and /'lɪniədʒ/ related?" is about pronunciation.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul re: Updatable/Updateable - No, that doesn’t answer my question. Normally the e is dropped when adding a suffix that begins with a vowel, so “updatable” would be the correct word. I guess my question is does line + -age = lineage. The suffix age starts with a vowel, so why keep the e?

Comment: I retracted my VTC.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=lineage) the Middle English word was *linage* ("line of descent; an ancestor"), which came from the Old French *lignage*.

"The word altered in spelling and pronunciation in early Modern English, apparently by some combined influence of line (n.) and lineal."

I wonder if there was further influence from 'linear' (from the French linéaire) and 'lineal' (from the Old French 'lineal'!)

Perhaps there was also an acknowledgement that a phoneme in the OF *lignage* had been elided in ME.

Comment: Spelling something "gn" in French works out to spelling things "ñ" in Spanish or sometimes "ny" in English. See *canyon* and *beignets*. So it was poorly spelt in ME. :)

Comment: @tchrist: That's what I meant, yes: shoddy spelling by those ME guys :) and then a correction in the Tudor period, when most printing was done in London and English became more uniform.

Comment: OED says: < Old French *lignage, linage* = Provençal *linhatge*, Spanish *linaje*, Portuguese *linhagem*, Italian *lignaggio*, *legnaggio* < Latin type **līneāticum* (see *-age* suffix), < *līnea* line n.² The spelling *lineage*, which appears late in the 17th cent., is probably due to association with *line* n.²; the modern pronunciation is influenced by *lineal* or Latin *līnea*.